# Cargar datos en un datatable usando LINQ C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datatable

Una vez mas vengo a requerir de su conocimiento del proyecto que estoy realizando tengo un método en el que hago uso de `Datatable` como se ve en el código es un poco ineficiente si hago la comparación con `Entity Framework`

```
public DataTable Cargar_Lista_Profesiona()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = conn,
                CommandText = "SELECT ODONT_APELLIDO+' '+ODONT_NOMBRE AS NOMBRE from [TBL_ODONTOLOGO] WHERE ODONT_ESTADO ='V' ORDER BY ODONT_APELLIDO"
            };
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            _ = da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Tratando de pasar todo el código a ef me queda de la siguiente manera pero el problema es como podría pasar lo que contiene la variable odontologo a el `DataTable`

```
public DataTable Cargar_Lista_Profesional()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var odontologo = db.TBL_ODONTOLOGO.Where(x => x.ODONT_ESTADO == "V").OrderByDescending(x => x.ODONT_APELLIDO).Select(x => new TBL_ODONTOLOGO
                {
                    ODONT_CODIGO = x.ODONT_CODIGO,
                    ODONT_NOMBRE = x.ODONT_NOMBRE,
                    ODONT_APELLIDO = x.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                    ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD = x.ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD,
                    ODONT_ID_TITULO = x.ODONT_ID_TITULO,
                    ODONT_FEC_NAC = x.ODONT_FEC_NAC,
                    ODONT_FEC_ELA = x.ODONT_FEC_ELA
                });
                dt = odontologo.; --> AQUI REQUIERO DE SU CONOCIMIENTO :(
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return dt;

    }
```

Después este método es usado para visualizar una lista de autocompletar en la cual recibe un `DataTable`

```
 public AutoCompleteStringCollection Cargar_Auto_Complete_Profesional()
    {
        DataTable dt = Cargar_Lista_Profesional();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            _ = stringCol.Add(Convert.ToString(row["NOMBRE"]));
        }
        return stringCol;
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Comment: Y porque quieres usar DataTables??? te presenta algún beneficio por sobre un  `List` ?

Comment: @Yussef edite la pregunta para que sepas el motivo por el cual lo necesito en un `DataTable`

Comment: Entonces, si entendí bien, la variable `odontologo` es `IEnumerable` y deseas convertirla a `DataTable`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich use la 2 formas, en la 1era me sale No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[]' al tipo 'System.Data.DataTable y en la 2da opción no me permite poner datasource

Comment: Me equivoque,  por eso borré el comentario. Lo que puse es para un datagridview. Para el DataTable me parece que es por medio de un datose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que tu función tiene muchas cosas que sobran.

1.- No necesitas usar `select` para retornar lo mismo que tienes en la lista, solo usalo si quieres algo distinto. Por lo que ese select sobra en TU función. Yo lo usuaré igualmente, porque transformaré esa lista un array de `string` (es decir, ya no retorno lo mismo, si no que estoy cambiando el contenido de la lista)

2.- No uses `using` para el dbcontext junto con un `try/cath`, solo creas sobre anidamiento, puedes llamar a Dispose con un finally (ahora esto es un detalle de gustos)

Esa función debería verse así:

Retornaremos un array de string

```
public string[] Cargar_Lista_Profesional()
{
    DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES()
    try
    {
        return db.TBL_ODONTOLOGO
            .Where(x => x.ODONT_ESTADO == "V")
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ODONT_APELLIDO)
            .Select(x => x.ODONT_APELLIDO +" "+ x.ODONT_NOMBRE).ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

Y la otra función:

```
public AutoCompleteStringCollection Cargar_Auto_Complete_Profesional()
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    stringCol.AddRange(Cargar_Lista_Profesional());
    return stringCol;
}
```

Comment: La función devuelve el tipo `List` y en el `return` usas `ToArray`. Esto producirá un error de conversión implícita.

Comment: Si justo estaba editando eso

Comment: Muchas gracias les agradezco por su colaboración y guía, son unos héroes sin capa,.

Comment: @Yussef en el caso de que desee incluir en ese arreglo otras columnas es viable o debería armar otro método?

Comment: @Carrobe90 entra acá https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143209/yussef para que me expliques

Answer (score 3):

Si entendí bien, tienes una variable de tipo `IEnumerable<T>` que llenas mediante una consulta de `System.Linq` y deseas convertir la misma al tipo `DataTable` junto a su contenido.

Para esto, una de tus mejores apuestas resulta ser el método de extensión [`CopyToDataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Data_DataTableExtensions_CopyToDataTable__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) contenido en el espacio de nombres `System.Data`.

---

En tu código, sería de esta forma:

<sup>Recuerda importar el espacio de nombres `System.Data`.</sup>

```
var odontologo = db.TBL_ODONTOLOGO.Where(x => x.ODONT_ESTADO == "V").OrderByDescending(x => x.ODONT_APELLIDO).Select(x => new TBL_ODONTOLOGO
{
    ODONT_CODIGO        = x.ODONT_CODIGO,
    ODONT_NOMBRE        = x.ODONT_NOMBRE,
    ODONT_APELLIDO      = x.ODONT_APELLIDO,
    ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD  = x.ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD,
    ODONT_ID_TITULO     = x.ODONT_ID_TITULO,
    ODONT_FEC_NAC       = x.ODONT_FEC_NAC,
    ODONT_FEC_ELA       = x.ODONT_FEC_ELA
});
            
dt = odontologo.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

// También admite la inferencia de tipos, es decir, dejas que el compilador deduzca el tipo
dt = odontologo.CopyToDataTable();
```

---

Y, si no te gusta la opción de Linq, puedes agregar las filas de forma manual recorriendo el enumerable con un iterador `foreach`.

Acá dejo un ejemplo ilustrativo bien simple:

```
foreach (TBL_ODONTOLOGO fila in odontologo)
{
    // Esto, sabiendo que previamente instanciaste tu DataTable
    dt.Rows.Add(fila);
}
```