# System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[]' al tipo DataSet C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataset

Una vez acudo a la sabiduría de ustedes, estoy haciendo uso de `Entity Framework` para llenar un dataset para visualizar en un reporte pero al momento de realizar el llamado cae en excepción en la linea que se detalla en el código.

Mi dataset se basa en una función que recibe un parametro de entrada que publico a continuación.

```
 create function [dbo].[fn_find_Presupuesto_Impresion]
    (@CODPRE varchar(10))
    RETURNS TABLE
            AS
            return(
    SELECT [PRE_COD]
          ,[PRE_COD_PAC]
          ,[PRE_NOM_PAC]
          ,[PRE_COD_ODON]
          ,[PRE_NOM_ODON]
          ,[PRE_RUT]
          ,[PRE_DEN_PAC]      
          ,[PRE_PIE_DEN]
          ,[PRE_TRA_PAC]
          ,[PRE_VAL_PRE]
          ,[PRE_VAL_POR]                  
          ,[PRE_VAL_DES]
          ,[PRE_VAL_SUB]
          ,[PRE_VAL_POR_DSC_SUB]  
          ,[PRE_VAL_TOT_DSC_SUB]
          ,[PRE_VAL_POR_TAR_SUB]
          ,[PRE_VAL_TOT_TAR_SUB]
           ,[PRE_VAL_TOT]
          ,[PRE_ELA_PRE]
          ,[PRE_EST_REA]
          ,[PRE_ID]
      FROM TBL_PRESUPUESTO
      where PRE_COD=@CODPRE)
```

Aquí coloco mi método en donde cae el error

```
public static DataSetImpresionPresupuesto PresupuestoCod(String CODPRE)
    {
        DataSetImpresionPresupuesto ds = new DataSetImpresionPresupuesto();
        DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES(); <-- AQUI SE GENERA LA EXCEPCION
        try
        {
            return ds = (DataSetImpresionPresupuesto)db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(x => x.PRE_COD == CODPRE);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Anteriormente tenia este código con el cual mandaba a llamar directamente enviando la sentencia y el parámetro que debía buscar.

```
public static DataSetImpresionPresupuesto PresupuestoCod(String CODPRE)
        {

            DataSetImpresionPresupuesto ds = new DataSetImpresionPresupuesto();
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_PRESUPUESTO WHERE PRE_COD=@CODPRE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODPRE", CODPRE);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            _ = da.Fill(ds, "Buscar_Presupuesto_Edicion");
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

Aquí coloco lo que contiene el `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto` y que posteriormente lo mando a llamar para poder llenar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo adjunto la imagen del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer la conversión que realizo no es la correcta, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Tu error no debe estar en esa línea, está en el return. Publica la clase DataSetImpresionPresupuesto

Comment: Si el error ocurre cuando instancias `new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES()` entonces necesitamos ver el código que tienes en esa clase, más específicamente en el constructor de la misma.

Comment: Además, a menos que tu clase `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto` implemente `IEnumerable` no puedes simplemente castear desde `Where` hacia la misma. Sería bueno ver el código de esta clase también. Porque me parece que más bien hereda de la clase `DataSet`.

Comment: hola @HéctorM. En este caso `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto` es un dataset basado en la función `fn_find_Presupuesto_Impresion` simplemente para en el .rpt mandar a llamar esa función y lo llene en base al código que indico no implemento `IEnumerable ` adicional orita puse como estaba anteriormente el metodo.

Comment: Bien, ya sé que `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto` hereda de la clase `DataSet`, pero, ¿qué tienes en el constructor de la clase `DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES`? ya que mencionas que al instanciarla te da error.

Comment: @HéctorM. `DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES` es donde toda el modelo de mi `Entity Framework` ya que el proyecto que se esta realizando se lo esta actualizando todo directamente a ef por lo cual ese código que se ve ya no es viable que se use todo tiene que ser llamado mediante ef por eso los cambios en el código :(

Comment: Yo sospecho que tienes el mismo problema que aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/584183/301324 , el cual es básicamente que estás cambiando  las funciones de tu APP (usando EF), pero no cambias los retornos de estas funciones

Comment: Coloca el código donde utilizas esta funcion `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto `

Comment: @Yussef la función `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto` solo la uso para hacer el llamado y como se ve en el código inicial para llenarlo y guardarlo en el `DataSet` y usarlo para visualizar en el .rpt. basicamente tendria que haciendo uso de `EF` hacer la conversion o el cast para almacenar el resultado de la consulta en el `DataSet`

Comment: Te explico: `db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(x => x.PRE_COD == CODPRE)` Esto devuelve un tipo de dato y tú lo quieres castear a `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto`, eso no se puede hacer de manera directa, hay que generar un código de conversión. Para ayudarte con esa parte se requiere conocer la implementación de la clase `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto`. Y de todos modos, tú estás mesclando 2 técnicas distintas "la antigua" que usa SQL, DataTable y SqlDataAdapter, con "la moderna" que es usando Entity framework, IQuereables e IEnummerables

Comment: Entonces la excepción no se dispara al hacer `new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES()` sino al intentar castear `IEnumerable` (o `IQueryable`) que es lo que devuelve `Where` a `DataSet`. Un casteo directo no se permite entre tipos no compatibles.

Comment: *Aquí coloco lo que contiene el `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto`...* mira, el error no se da por el contenido, sino porque en el código intentas realizar una conversión no permitida. Necesitamos ver el código dentro de tu clase `DataSetImpresionPresupuesto` y tu clase `DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES`.